# TS - Tagged template literals and function signature

Tags: typescript, types

I have this factory function which uses template tag:

```js
function logWithNamespace([ns]: TemplateStringsArray) {
  return (...args) => console.log(ns, ...args);
}

const log = logWithNamespace `foo`;

log(1, 2, 3); // => 'foo', 1, 2, 3
```

Now I need to add function signature like this:

```js
function logWithNamespace<T>([ns]: TemplateStringsArray) {
  return (thing: T) => console.log(ns, thing);
}

const log = logWithNamespace<number> `number`;

log(1); // => 'number', 1
```

I get this typescript syntax error:

```js
/*
 * Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'string'.
 */
```

#### how can I add function signature to functions returned by tagged template literals?

---

**Note:** I don't like the use of *[Tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)* for this purpose, but this is a requirement.

**Note:** [Tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) can return something different from a string.

Comment: Currently you can't specify generic parameter [more info](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11947). But you can just use: `const log = logWithNamespace ``number``;` Obviously you'll lose number constraint

Answer (score 1):

As @AlekseyL mentioned, you [can't do that](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11947) directly.

If you're willing to do it *indirectly*, there's always something like this:

```
const makeLogWithNamespace = <T>() => ([ns]: TemplateStringsArray) => {
  return (thing: T) => console.log(ns, thing);
}

const log = makeLogWithNamespace<number>() `number`;
log(1); // => 'number', 1
```

The function `makeLogWithNamespace<T>()` is a generic factory which returns a non-generic `logWithNamespace()` function, where `T` is replaced by something concrete, like `number`.  You can then use that as a tag function without problems.

For the developer there's just that extra set of parentheses to add, but it should work.  Hope that helps; good luck!

---

EDIT: If this solution doesn't work for someone, please let me know what the issue is so I can address it.  Thanks!